# Configure GitLab CI to run test only on specific tags

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

For a Python project hosted on GitLab, I have a CI build configured as shown below. For every push, the CI build runs a test suite, style checks, and builds the documentation. When branches are merged to master, the CI build performs and extra step to push the built docs to GitLab Page's hosting site.

I would like to configure another job only to be executed on release candidates—git tags that include `rc` in the name. The [GitLab CI reference docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/) include several references to `if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG`, but I'm struggling to understand how to put it all together.

---

```yaml
before_script:
  - apt-get update -qy
  - apt-get install -y ...
  - pip3 install ...
  - pip3 install --no-deps --ignore-installed .
test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - make test
    - make style
    - make doc
pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - apt-get update -qy
    - apt-get install -y ...
    - pip3 install ...
    - pip3 install --no-deps --ignore-installed .
    - sphinx-build -b html docs/ public
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  only:
    - master
```

---

**UPDATE/SOLUTION**

Based on the answer from @danielnelz I was able to come up with the following working solution.

```yaml
before_script:
  - apt-get update -qy
  - apt-get install -y ...
  - pip3 install ...
  - pip3 install --no-deps --ignore-installed .

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - make test
    - make style
    - make doc

prerelease:
  stage: test
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /rc/'
  script:
    - make testrc

pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - sphinx-build -b html docs/ public
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  only:
    - master
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the predefined `$CI_COMMIT_TAG` contains rc in a [rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/#rules) clause:

```
release:
  stage: release
  script:
    - do release
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /rc/'
```